# What can be configured using ServletRegistration.Dynamic?

Tags: java, servlets, listener

It's a question about Java certification 1Z0-899.
I must choose two answers.

The question is:

> #### ServletRegistration.Dynamic can be used to configure:
>
> A) Filter mappings
>   B) add init params
>   C) set asyncSupported to true
>   D) add Listeners

I think that should be correct B, C. But my text says A, B.
Who is right?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: It says: "Interface through which a Servlet registered via one of the addServlet methods on ServletContext may be further configured."
And it have only 3 methods that doesn't seem relate to the answers...

Comment: Don't forget to look at superclass methods. setInitParameter() and setAsyncSupported() seem quite related to the answers, don't you think?

Comment: thanks! The superclass of the superclass :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A) To configure Filter mappings you can use
`FilterRegistration.Dynamic.addMappingForServletNames(java.util.EnumSet dispatcherTypes, boolean b, java.lang.String... strings)` or `FilterRegistration.Dynamic.(java.util.EnumSet dispatcherTypes, boolean b, java.lang.String... strings)`

B) For adding initParams - `ServletRegistration.Dynamic.setInitParameter(java.lang.String s, java.lang.String s1)` or `ServletRegistration.Dynamic. setInitParameters(java.util.Map stringStringMap)`

C) Set asyncSupported to true `ServletRegistration.Dynamic.setAsyncSupported(boolean b)`

D) Add listeners with `ServletContext.addListener(T t)`

That means rigth answer is B and C

Answer (score 1):

From The specs  pages 31 of Servlet Context 3.0:

> **4.4.1 Programmatically adding and configuring Servlets**
>
> The ability to programmatically add a servlet to a context is useful
>   for framework developers. For example a framework could declare a
>   controller servlet using this method. The return value of this method
>   is a ServletRegistration or a ServletRegistration.Dynamic object which
>   further allows you to setup the other parameters of the servlet like
>   init-params, url-mappings etc. There are three overloaded versions of
>   the method as described below.

you can see that they mention init-params and url-mappings.

So maybe who create this question/Answer choose this text :) , moreover the ServletRegistration.Dynamic is for configure your servlets created or add it by the Servlet Context programmatically like add mapping,init-param and set the security-constraints properties...

Thank you